# How to create NSMutableArray in which objects follow protocol?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, protocols

How to create NSMutableArray  in which objects follow protocol?
For example in swift I can do something like:
`var array:[MyProtocol] = []` 
How to implement that in objC

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C you declare a variable of protocol type by declaring it as `id<SomeProtocol>`, e.g.:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol<NSObject>
...
@end

@interface SomeClass : NSObject<SomeProtocol> // base class NSObject, implements SomeProtocol
...
@end

@implementation SomeClass
...
@end

// a variable declaration somewhere which holds a reference to any object
// which implements SomeProtocol
id<SomeProtocol> anyObjectImplementingSomeProtocol = SomeClass.new;
```

Using Objective-C's *lightweight generics* you can extend this to containers of protocol type, e.g.:

```
NSMutableArray<id<SomeProtocol>> someArray = NSMutableArray.new;
```

**Warning:** Lightweight generics are named that for a reason, it is quite easy to bypass the restrictions imposed by them, e.g. by adding an object which does not implement `SomeProtocol` to `someArray`. You don't get the same strong generics as in Swift.

HTH